# Trying to figure out how the 'with..as' construct works in python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and I landed on the

> with..as

construct, that used like this:

```
with open("somefile.txt", 'rt') as file:
    print(file.read()) 
    # at the end of execution file.close() is called automatically.
```

So as a learning strategy I tried to do the following:

```
class Derived():

    def __enter__(self):
        print('__enter__')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('__exit__')

with  Derived() as derived:
    print(derived)
```

and I got this output:

```
__enter__
None
__exit__
```

My question is then:

- why did `print(derived)` return a `None` object and not a `Derived` object?

Comment: `__enter__` must return the object that is bound to `dervied`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The name `derived` is bound to the object returned by the `__enter__` method, which is `None`. Try:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print('__enter__')
    return self
```

[Docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers)

> `object.__enter__(self)`
>
> Enter the runtime context related to this object. The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement will bind this method’s return value to the target(s) specified in the [`as`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#as) clause of the statement, if any.

Comment: I looked everywhere I wasn't able to read this anywhere? How could I have figured it out? is there a manual explaining this requirement anywhere?

Comment: @Kam Updated with the doc reference